# HTML page for indexing multiple images

Tags: html

I have 200+ .PNG files for work related instructions. I was thinking I should probably make some kind of tool to aid me with opening the proper image file. Browsing for right files through Windows Explorer gets pretty tedious. Maybe a simple HTML page would do the trick?

The instructions are "sub categorized" in this manner:
[set 1] [set 2] [set 3] ... [set x]
Clicking open set 1 would offer options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. and each of these options would offer 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and so forth. Clicking 1.3 would open the corresponding .PNG into a frame below. (Preferably not a new window or anything cause I have to browse through the files a lot and continuously, and I'd prefer as little clicking as possible. That's why opening the files through Explorer is annoying.)

I haven't done any HTML related stuff in 10+ years, so I'm a bit rusty atm. What kind of elements/divs/frames/whatever should I look into? I browsed around a bit, but couldn't anything fitting for my needs so I wasn't able to take the source and try to tailor it to my needs.

Is it also possible to generate a random number each time I click I file open? It's probably some JavaScript thing, no?

GIMP sketch to illustrate it, lo & behold.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGgwh.png

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript is not able to access the local file system.

Comment: What do you mean? If I'm able to open the files in browser, why not? Couldn't I just put the images in the same directory as the .html file?

Comment: yes, but to view the images you would have to hard code it someway because even when loaded locally, JS doesn't have functions to read the filesystem, unless you were to make a full fledged app with something like [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)